# How to change values and create new elements?

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm new to XQuery. Is there any way to use XQuery to turn this input

```
<mods>
    <subject>
        <topic> bird ; cat ; dog ; lion </topic>
    </subject>
</mods>
```

into following XML?

```
<mods>
    <subject>
        <topic> bird </topic><topic> cat </topic><topic> dog </topic><topic> lion </topic>
    </subject>
</mods>
```

I tried to use the function

```
replace(node,';','</topic><topic>' )
```

but it turns the angle `<` `>` brackets into its entity reference `&lt;` or `&gt;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your XQuery Processor supports XQuery Update, you can try the following query:

```
copy $xml := document {
  <mods>
    <subject>
        <topic> bird ; cat ; dog ; lion </topic>
    </subject>
  </mods>
}
modify (
  let $topic := $xml/mods/subject/topic
  return replace node $topic with
    for $token in tokenize($topic, ';')
    return <topic>{ $token }</topic>
)
return $xml
```

Answer (score 2):

`replace(...)` only works on strings, not on elements. `'</topic><topic>'` (a string) and `</topic><topic>` (invalid XML) are not the same!

Reconstruct the result (you might also be able to use XQuery Update), and tokenize each `<topic/>` element, creating new topic items for each of them:

```
element mods {
  element subject {
    for $topics in /mods/subject/topic
    for $topic in tokenize($topics, ';')
    return element topic { $topic }
  }
}
```

For constructing new elements, I prefer the computed element constructors used above. `element nodeName { $content }` is equivalent to using `<nodeName>{ $content }</nodeName>`.